# Work with Foundation 6 in Angular 2

Tags: angular, zurb-foundation, angular2-template, zurb-foundation-6

As I know I should put *$(this.elementRef.nativeElement).foundation()* in each component when I want use foundation. But I couldn't understand in what part I should do it.

For example I need use dropdown on hover.

```
<div data-toggle="skill-dropdown">Skills</div>
<div id="skill-dropdown" data-dropdown data-hover="true" data-hover-pane="true">
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let skill of skillsList">
        <div>{{skill.title}}</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Angular Hooks like AfterViewInit or AfterContentInit doesn't help in this case.

As solution I should use setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    $(this.elementRef.nativeElement).foundation();
}, 5000);
```

Is there some other good solution for this task?

P.S $(document).foundation() also doesn't work.

Comment: does it really takes `5000`(5 sec) or it work for `1000` (1sec) as well? could you please add component and its HTML as well

Comment: @PankajParkar main part of template is in question. In component I haven't  logic, only hard code array.

Answer (score 0):

As I haven't found any working solution for foundation javascript and angular 2 to work properly I'm stuck with this in my Main/App Component

```js
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

    private _router: Router;

    constructor(router: Router) {
        this._router = router;
    }

    public ngOnInit() {
        this._router.events.subscribe((event: any) => {
            if(event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
                jQuery(document).foundation();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This works for most simple things. Foundation Orbit has some issues with this usage. I still hope, that Zurb will reveal Foundation Apps 2 soon, so Foundation Sites JavaScript can be replaced with native Angular 2 directives.

For your question you might check if adding `$(this.elementRef.nativeElement).foundation()` into the `ngOnInit()` of your component works.
Best would be to use something like `new Foundation.Dropdown(this.elementRef.nativeElement);` in `ngOnInit()` but I also didn't get this to work properly.

Maybe some of the hints may help you to create a working solution. Would like to hear if you can make it work.